# What's the last song that the Expendables team members sing?

Tags: ending, soundtrack, the-expendables-2

Just back from seeing *The Expendables 2* and was wondering what was the last song the Expendables team sing at the end?

Comment: You might add why knowing what they sang was important, otherwise this risks being closed as trivia.

Comment: just being curious.

Comment: Unless there is some big significance to the plot this song provides, this question just looks like trivia to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the lyrics of the team hymn:

> *Beware, Beware, Walk With Care*
>
> *Careful what You Do*
>
> *Or Mumbo Jumbo's Gonna Hoodoo You,*
>
> *Mumbo Jumbo Is Gonna Hoodoo You,*
>
> *Boomlay, Boomlay, Boomlay, Boom!*

It's a military cadence based on the 1912 Vachel Lindsay's poem "The Congo" (available [here](http://ipoet.com/archive/rhythmic/Lindsay/congo.html)).